# Can i connect to Redis via http URL hits without having to download anything like WebDis

Tags: redis

The heading basically says it all. i need to connect to my redis server to find the status of my queues , their queue sizes remotely. I wanted to now if something like that exists already or not? I wouldnt prefer installing something to connect like webdis etc.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to programatically access to it? Or do you just want a GUI?

For a GUI you may want to give a try to [**Redsmin**](https://redsmin.com), it's online so you don't need to install anything else.

Comment: no i dont want to a GUI. I need to programatically access it. I need to build an alerting system over the queues .

Comment: I am sorry I don't know any tools/services that currently do that. (and that's why we already started to write an alerting system in Redsmin)

Answer (score 1):

no thats not possible, Redis only offers a telnet like connection.